# 3 finger swipe gesture while on guest user account

Tags: mac, macos, trackpad, guest-account

Firstly, I have the latest OS X installed (10.11.2) and when I log in to the Mac with my administration account everything regarding the trackpad gestures works smoothly.

What impresses me is that  when I create a guest user account, then I cannot resize any window with the 3 finger swipe gesture (yes, I have checked the settings). However, if I press hard the trackpad and swipe, then it works.

Does anyone have a similar problem?

- I have already tried SMC/PRAM reset and deleting/disabling the account but the problem persists.

**UPDATE**: This problem occurs no matter the type of account I create (i.e. even if I create an extra administration account).

Comment: Ok, solution found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6996855?start=0&tstart=0), for anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @thanasissdr for answering your own question:

1. To enable 3-finger swipe on any account, go to System Preferences > Accessibility.
2. On the right, choose Mouse & Trackpad.
3. Click "Trackpad Options..."
4. Check "Enable dragging" and select "three finger drag" from the drop-down list.

Here's the Apple [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6996855?start=0&tstart=0) that answers this question.